# CSS changing margin of the entire website, is there anyway to override this?

Tags: html, css

When I add a css doc for a form it destroys my page margin. I have already tried changing all margins and paddings to 0 but didn't help. The only way this works is by removing the entire css file.  I have also tried deleting all body references in the css but the issue persisted. I have also tried to add !important to the main css of the page. I am not sure what is causing this issue in the css file. When I inspect the code in the browser it does not show that this css is being used.

[image: issue image]

```
body {
    margin: 0px;

    aside {
        background: #1f8dd6; /* same color as selected state on site menu */
        padding: 0.3em 1em;
        border-radius: 3px;
        color: #fff;
        margin-bottom: 2em;
    }
    textarea {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .content-head {
        font-weight: 400;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 0.1em;
        margin: 2em 0 1em;
    }
    .is-center {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .button-success {
        color: white;
        border-radius: 4px;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        background: rgb(28, 184, 65); /* this is a green */
    }
    .button-xlarge {
        font-size: 125%;
    }
    button {
        float: right;
    }
    #name, #email {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css file contains every class,element,id twice. Hence it is giving problem.

Remove all code from your css file and paste this,

```
  body {
  margin: 0px;
  aside {
    background: #1f8dd6;
    /* same color as selected state on site menu */
    padding: 0.3em 1em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
  }
  textarea {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .content-head {
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    margin: 2em 0 1em;
  }
  .is-center {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .button-success {
    color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: rgb(28, 184, 65);
    /* this is a green */
  }
  .button-xlarge {
    font-size: 125%;
  }
  button {
    float: right;
  }
  #name,
  #email {
    width: 50%;
  }
```